# Grafico con Horas y Minutos

Tags: javascript, chart.js

Buenos días,
Estoy intentando hacer un gráfico que muestre las horas y minutos totales de clases que da un profesor al mes. Tan solo he logrado que muestre en la linea las horas pero me gustaría que saliesen los minutos también. La consulta la hago en PHP y luego paso las variables a JS. Gracias:

```
<div class="panel-body">Taught hours chart
                        <div class="canvas-wrapper">
                            <canvas class="main-chart" id="line-chart" height="200" width="600"></canvas>
                        </div>
                    </div>    
<script>
    var horas_mes1 = '<?php echo $horas2_mes1 ?>';
    var min_mes1 = '<?php echo $min2_mes1 ?>';
    var horas_mes2 = '<?php echo $horas2_mes2 ?>';
    var min_mes2 = '<?php echo $min2_mes2 ?>';
    var horas_mes3 = '<?php echo $horas2_mes3 ?>';
    var min_mes3 = '<?php echo $min2_mes3 ?>';
    var horas_mes4 = '<?php echo $horas2_mes4 ?>';
    var min_mes4 = '<?php echo $min2_mes4 ?>';
    var horas_mes5 = '<?php echo $horas2_mes5 ?>';
    var min_mes5 = '<?php echo $min2_mes5 ?>';
    var mes1letra = '<?php echo $mes1letra ?>';
    var mes2letra = '<?php echo $mes2letra ?>';
    var mes3letra = '<?php echo $mes3letra ?>';
    var mes4letra = '<?php echo $mes4letra ?>';
    var mes5letra = '<?php echo $mes5letra ?>';

    var lineChartData = {
        labels :[mes1letra,mes2letra,mes3letra,mes4letra,mes5letra],
        datasets : [
            {
                label: "My First dataset",
                fillColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 0.2)",
                strokeColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                pointColor : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(48, 164, 255, 1)",
                data : [horas_mes1,horas_mes2,horas_mes3,horas_mes4,horas_mes5]
            }
        ]
    }
    window.onload = function(){
    var chart1 = document.getElementById("line-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(chart1).Line(lineChartData, {
        responsive: true,
        scaleLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.2)", 
        scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.05)", 
        scaleFontColor: "#ffffff"
    });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Sería interesante que subieras un jsfiddle para ver cómo sale actualmente.

Comment: Podría poner una imagen...

Comment: La idea es publicar un [mcve] que ayude a entender el problema, no se vaya por las ramas y permita replicarlo localmente para poder ofrecer una solución.

Comment: No haria falta ni un jsfiddle, usando la opcion de fragmentos de codigo de JS/HTML/CSS en el editor de la pregunta es suficiente

Comment: Gracias por contestar... he editado la pregunta poniendo el CANVAS... perdonad pero es que soy algo novato en estos temas y me sabe mal molestar pero cuando llego a un punto que me atasco pregunto... Saludos

Comment: He encontrado un ejemplo que es exáctamente como me sale a mi el gráfico. Necesitaría que en vez de valores enteros en la curva, me saliesen las horas y minutos http://jsfiddle.net/mbhavfwm/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para empezar, creo sería mejor:

- Anexar las horas con los minutos para tener un total de horas decimal, por ejemplo: `49.50 horas`, donde la parte fraccionaria equivale a los minutos.
- Obtener los datos por ajax, porque la [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) es una librería que necesita los datos disponibles en JavaScript.

> En este punto supongo que se tiene en la base de datos los minutos extra de clases, ya que, tener la cantidad de horas y la misma cantidad en minutos (h * 60) no tendría ningún sentido.

Digamos que traes de la base de datos las horas y minutos de clase por cada mes:

```
$monthHours = array(
  "mes1" => 75,
  "mes2" => 80,
  "mes3" => 83
  "mes4" => 78
);

$monthMinutes = array(
  "mes1" => 25,
  "mes2" => 37,
  "mes3" => 18,
  "mes4" => 29
);
```

En el cliente, lo que podemos hacer es saber *el porcentaje de 1h de cada minuto*. Matemática básica: si `1h = 60m = 100% | Xm = %?`.

```
const totalHours = [];
for (let key in monthHours) {
  const val = monthHours[key];
  const minute = monthMinutes[key] / 100;
  totalHours.push(val + minute);
}
```

> En caso envíes las horas desde el backend en un array simple (no asociativo) como `$monthHours = array(75, 80, 83, 78)`, entonces lo anterior se puede realizar usando `Array#map`.

```
const totalHours = hours.map(function (hour, i) {
  const minute = minutes[i] / 100;
  return hour += minute;
});
```

**Tooltips personalizados en Chart.js**

Chart.js nos permite personalizar los tooltips para mostrar información personalizada. Ésta funcionalidad es útil por ejemplo cuando trabajamos con monedas. Para personalizar los tooltips, basta con crear un objeto con la llave `tooltips.callbacks.label`. Ésta llave acepta una función que recibe dos parámetros: tooltip actual y objeto `data` (nuestros datasets).

```
const options = {
  tooltips: {
    callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltip, data) {
        const index = tooltip.index;
        let hours = data.datasets[0].data[index];
        let minutes = (hours % 1).toFixed(2);
        hours = parseInt(hours);
        minutes = minutes.substring(minutes.indexOf('.') + 1);
        return `${hours} horas y ${minutes} minutos`;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

En el código de arriba solo extraemos la hora del label sobre el cual se ha hecho hover. Posteriormente, extraemos los minutos de las horas y le damos el formato siguiente:

> X horas y Y minutos

Una vez que ya tenemos todo, lo juntamos y obtenemos el resultado deseado.

Puedes ver código en funcionamiento a continuación (o también en [éste fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/guzgarcia/7rod2yxu/4)):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
 const ctx = document.getElementById('draw').getContext('2d');

  let monthHours = {
    mes1: 78,
    mes2: 80,
    mes3: 83,
    mes4: 78,
    mes5: 79
  };
  let monthMinutes = {
    mes1: 25,
    mes2: 37,
    mes3: 18,
    mes4: 29,
    mes5: 32
  };
  const totalHours = [];

  for (let key in monthHours) {
    const val = monthHours[key];
    const minute = monthMinutes[key];
    totalHours.push(val + (minute / 100));
  }
  const labels = ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo'];
  const datasets = [
    {
      label: 'Horas de clases',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 255, .13)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 255, .35)',
      pointColor: '#3498db',
      pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 150, 255, .55)',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#fff',
      data: totalHours
    }
  ];
  const options = {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: function (tooltip, data) {
          const index = tooltip.index;
          let hours = data.datasets[0].data[index];
          let minutes = (hours % 1).toFixed(2);
          hours = parseInt(hours);
          minutes = minutes.substring(minutes.indexOf('.') + 1);
          return `${hours} horas y ${minutes} minutos`;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  new Chart.Line(ctx, {
    data: { labels, datasets },
    options
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Chart.js -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- HTML (canvas) -->
<section class="chart">
  <canvas id="draw" height="300" width="700"></canvas>
</section>
```

Comment: Perfectísimo @guzgarcia. Funciona a la perfección. Te agradezco mucho este esfuerzo!

Comment: Una última pregunta.. a veces no me lo carga... debería ponerle window.onload = function(){  ????

Comment: Claro, la gráfica debe ser cargado una vez el documento ha sido renderizado. En `window#onload` o `document#DOMContentLoaded` sirve.

Comment: Gracias, y en el fiddle lo podrías poner? es que a mi me funcionaba así: window.onload = function(){

window.myLine = new Chart(chart1).Line(lineChartData, {
 responsive: true,
 scaleLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.2)", 
 scaleGridLineColor: "rgba(255,255,255,.05)", 
 scaleFontColor: "#ffffff"
});
}

Comment: Ya está, en lugar `/4` al final de la URL del fiddle, ponle `/5`.

Comment: Gracias! por alguna razón, en mi código no me funciona...  copio y pego el código del fiddle y me aparece en blanco... voy a investigar a ver.

Comment: Mira la consola del navegador, si hay un problema lo verás allí. ¿Añadiste la librería al HTML?

Comment: Si quieres lo podemos pasar al chat... perdoname pero es que no sé que librería dices... tengo librerias cargadas en mi html pero no se a la que te refieres.

Comment: La librería que necesitas agregar es Chart.js ([click aquí](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.4.0/Chart.min.js)), que es la que te permite realizar las gráficas. Solo la agregas y tendrás funcionando todo.

Comment: Funciona!!!! gracias por todo. Lo único que tengo que ver es de hacer bien el cálculo porque yo ya hago una consulta que me da bien las horas y minutos del mes...

Comment: guzgarcia una pregunta, ...las horas me salen multiplicadas por 10... es decir, lo hace todo bien pero por ejemplo, si son 51 horas, me pone 510... sabrías que puede ser? haciendo alert a la variable me da 51 tb. Gracias

Comment: No tiene por qué hacer eso. Al parecer es problema de backend ya que el código que hace la gráfica lo único que hace es dividir los minutos entre 100 para convertirse en 0.x y sumarse a las horas. ¿Te aseguraste que la consulta te traiga correctamente las horas y minutos?

Comment: Mañana le echare un vistazo... a mi tb me extraña pero cuando hago un echo de las variables php me salen bien... extraño. Gracias por contestar

Comment: @guzgarcia muy buena respuesta. ¿Por algún motivo específico estás publicando en jsfiddle y no en la respuesta como snippet? No tiene nada de malo en este caso, pero sería más cómodo verlo acá y no tener que abrir el enlace

Comment: Hola Mariano, en realidad lo intenté pero me salía un error (genérico) de script cuando se ejecutaba (aunque se visualizaba) y tapaba un poco la gráfica.

Comment: @guzgarcia lo agregué a la respuesta activando la opción para que no muestre la consola

Comment: Genial Mariano, gracias.

Comment: Buenas tardes @guzgarcia. Al parecer todas las variables de la consulta están bien. Lo he podido solucionar poniendo un /1 a esto... const val = monthHours[key] / 1;

Comment: Genial. Me alegro que ya todo funcione correctamente.